# Calculating volume by shell integration

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

$y = \ln x$, region is delimited by $y = -1$, $y = 2$ and the $y$-axis, it rotates around the $y$-axis. 
[image]

It's quite simple to solve by using disk integration but I can't get it right with shell integration, I want to understand what I'm doing wrong:

$x = e^{y}$

$y = -1 \rightarrow x = 1/e$

$y = 2 \rightarrow x = e^2$

$$
V =  2\pi * \int_{1/e}^{e^2} x\ \ln x \;\mathrm{d}x
$$

Integrating that does not get me to the right answer which is $\pi/2(e^4 - e^{-2})$

Comment: I don't know what region is being rotated. Is it "above" $y=\ln x$ or "below"? If below, then the height of the cylindrical shell "at" $x$ is $\ln x-(-1)$.

Comment: I edited it to include a picture to make things more clear but someone has already solved it.

Comment: So, in the language of my comment, it is "above." The problem should then have said bounded by $\ln x$, $y=-1$, $y=2$, and the $y$-axis. If using shells we need to break up the integral into $2$ parts, $x=0$ to $e^{-1}$ and the rest. And past $x=e^{-1}$ the height of the shell is $2-\ln x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You have missed what I have marked as $(1)$, and made a mistake in writing the shell integration for $(2)$.

For the integral,  you need to consider the *height* of each cylindrical shell. $y=2$ is the upper bound, so the height is $2-\ln x$. The volume each infinitesimal cylindrical shell contributes will be $height*2\pi*radius*d(radius)$, in your case $(2-\ln x)2\pi x dx$. Integrating this, we get:

$$\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e^2} 2 \pi  x (2-\log (x)) \, dx=\frac{\left(e^6-7\right) \pi }{2 e^2}$$

Now we need the inner cylinder (which is not really a function, it is a simple cylinder, so I will calculate it as a regular cylinder). The volume will be:

$$3\pi (e^{-1})^2$$

Summing the two volume, you get:

$$\frac{\left(e^6-1\right) \pi }{2 e^2}$$